# UIView Constraints TextView contentSize Bug

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a function that returns a `UIView`. I want to dynamically change the size of my `UIView`(fullView) based on how much text is shown in the `UITextView`(thirdTextView).

I have tried setting the height dependant on the `sizeThatFits` of `thirdTextView` but it outputs "30" every time? What am I doing wrong?

```
let fullView = UIView()

    fullView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.82, green:0.83, blue:0.85, alpha:1.0)

    let firstButton = UIButton()
    firstButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let secondButton = UIButton()
    secondButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let thirdTextView = UITextView()
    thirdTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    thirdTextView.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
    thirdTextView.backgroundColor = .clear
    thirdTextView.isScrollEnabled = false

    firstButton.setTitle("Button1", for: .normal)
    firstButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    firstButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
    firstButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left

    secondButton.setTitle("Button2", for: .normal)
    secondButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    secondButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
    secondButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right

    let descriptionBarStackView =  UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [firstButton, UIView() ,secondButton])
    descriptionBarStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    descriptionBarStackView.axis = .horizontal
    descriptionBarStackView.alignment = .fill

    let viewWithStackViews = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [descriptionBarStackView, thirdTextView])
    viewWithStackViews.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewWithStackViews.axis = .vertical
    viewWithStackViews.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 10, bottom: 5, right:10)
    viewWithStackViews.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true

    fullView.addSubview(viewWithStackViews)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: descriptionBarStackView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        viewWithStackViews.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        viewWithStackViews.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        viewWithStackViews.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        viewWithStackViews.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        ])


    let test = thirdTextView.sizeThatFits(thirdTextView.frame.size).height
    print(test)

    fullView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textView.frame.width - 10, height: test)

    fullView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    return fullView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here you add constraints between `fullView` and `view` while it's not a subview

```
 fullView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
 fullView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
 fullView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

May be you miss

```
self.view.addSubview(fullView)
```

> For rendering purposes there are many ways
>
> 1- Giving it a frame
>
> 2- Giving the view width/height
>
> 3- Adding it as a subview but hidden

Best option is the first

Comment: Yeah, I need those constraints though and I don't want a subview added...

Comment: I am using the function to render an image of the return view. I don't want it to also be added as a subView.

Comment: this is n't a bug to add constraints between 2 views there must be a hierarchy between them , that's how auto-layout works

Comment: Yep, how can I go about working around this though? If I don't want it added as a subView?

Comment: you need to give it width/height constraints only or a frame  or you can add it with `fullvView.isHidden=true`  and remove after rendering , rendering works also if the view is hidden

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'm confused by why I can add width to a different view in the frame with. fullView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textView.frame.width, height: 90) But can't add it in a constraint. It seems cumbersome having to add then delete the view...Is it?

Comment: i'm giving you all options sure frame option is the best

Comment: 1. & 2. I am having a problem because I can't give it a frame as I need the height to change dependant on how much text is in thirdTextView. Is there a different way I can achieve a frame? 3. I can't add it as a subView as I am using it to render an image and if it's hidden the image renders as white.

Comment: Can I use a frame and somehow get the height of thirdTextview?